# How to use search using Ajax in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel-4

im trying to search a values from database to retreive corresponding data form database to text box using laravel. the problem is..im enter a value but no result.
my controller.php

```
public function executeSearch()
{
    $keywords=Input::get('keywords');
    $users=User::all();
    $searchUsers=new\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection();
    foreach($users as $u)
    {
        if(Str::contains(Str::Lower($u->username),Str::Lower($keywords)))
            $searchUsers->add($u);
    }
    return View::make('searchUsers')
    ->with('users',$searchUsers);
}
```

search js page

```
var keywords=$('#search-input').val();
    if(keywords.length>0)
    {
        $.post('http://localhost/lara/lara/public/search',{keywords:keywords},function(markup)
        {
            $('#search-result').html(markup);
        });
    }
```

i think problem is this line ...$.post('http://localhost/lara/lara/public/search',{keywords:keywords},function(markup)

Comment: you can check in your browser if request is being posted or not.
It seems that you have not associated any event handler like onkeyup or onblur.

Comment: sorry.can you explain?

Comment: my search.js page is.. var timer;
function up()
{
 timer=setTimeout(function()
 {
  var keywords=$('#search-input').val();
  if(keywords.length>0)
  {
   $.post('http://localhost/lara/lara/public/search',{keywords:keywords},function(markup)
   {
    $('#search-result').html(markup);
   });
  }
 }
 500);
}
function down()
{
 clearTimeout(timer);
}

Comment: where is the function `up` is being called?

Comment: my search.blade.php is...<input type="text" id="search-input" class="form-control"
 placeholder="search" onkeydown="down()" onkeyup="up()">

Comment: my searchUsers.blade.php is...@foreach($searchUser as $u)
<b>{{$u->username}}</b></br>
@endforeach

Comment: You can check if the url is being posted or not in your browse.
In chromer network.

Comment: my routes ...Route::get('/',function()
{
 return View::make('search');

});
Route::post('executeSearch',array('uses'=>'SearchController@executeSearch'));

Comment: You are calling `http://localhost/lara/lara/public/search` and set route to `executeSearch`. Can you use `http://localhost/lara/lara/public/executeSearch`

Comment: my search.js is var keywords=$('#search-input').val();
  if(keywords.length>0)
  {
   $.post('http://localhost/search/lara/public/search/executesearch', {keywords:keywords},function(markup)
   {
    $('#search-result').html(markup);
   });
  } im calling path is $.post('http://localhost/lara/lara/public/search/executesearch', {keywords:keywords},function(markup)
 is it right or wrong?

Comment: wrong..it should be http://localhost/lara/lara/public/executeSearch otherwise you have change route

Comment: thnks... but im working...no error occur...bt no display anything....what i do?

Comment: Do you have team viewever? mail me amitfts@gmail.com

Comment: sorry no team viewever

Comment: my problem when i type a letter in onkeyup action searching db and that letter starting words are display below ...its nt work.. how can fetch value from database to this code...